# Converting int to String of its ASCII

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I'm looking a way to convert an integer for example 50, to its ASCII as string.

So far, I tried casting integer to char with

```
int a = 57 ;
char c = char(a);
```

But I couldnt convert that char into string. Looking forward to your help!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @bolov, I don't believe that's what he meant, he probably means getting the ASCII value of the integer when it's a char .

Comment: What string do you want? "50"?

Comment: Resolved with the link Thanks guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

```
int a = 50;
std::string s(1, char(a));
```

Using the "fill"  constructor (2).

Answer (score 3):

A string is a squence of char and 0 at end.

```
int a = 57 ;
char c[2] = { (char)a, 0 };
```

-

```
#include <string>

std::string str;
str += (char)a;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `std::string` be more common and useful in C++?

Comment: Well personally I would teach the simple high level abstraction before the messy and error prone low level mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question..the value of `int` is already the ASCII value.
In your example, 57 is the ASCII value for character 9. Then you can't convert that character to integer where in fact you were the one that declared its value.

If you want character to its ASCII value:

```
char b;
cin>>b;
int a = int (b);
```